# Empirical Bernstein Bound for distributions outside range(0,1)

Tags: machine-learning, probability, statistical-significance, probability-inequalities, bounds

I'm working on using empirical Bernstein bounds to estimate the mean difference between 2 variables from different distribution.

The algorithm samples from each variable until it detects a significant difference between the 2 variables. Upon termination, it returns an estimate of the mean difference.

I noticed that the literature on empirical Bernstein bound has exclusively tested using simulated uniform and Bernoulli random variables, [e.g. variables in the range 0,1](https://hal-enpc.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00834983/file/ICML08b.pdf). My question is how far the algorithm performs well when used with other distributions? (One may not always know the distribution of the data.)

From what I understand, the application to uniform and Bernoulli random variables stems from the fact that Hoeffding made the range (0,1) assumption to get a simple form of the bound. Hoeffding for example states that if the assumption of the range (0,1) is dropped, i.e. if the variable is non-negative with finite Mean, then the Markov inequality cannot be improved upon. At least this is the explanation I found in Hoeffding's paper [(see footnote 4, p.15)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2282952?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents):

Quote:
"If in Theorem 1 (Hoeffding inequality) the assumption Xi <1 is dropped
that is, if it is only assumed that the Xi are non-negative with finite means, then Markov's inequality
$Pr(\bar{X}-\mu\geq t)\leq\mu/(\mu+t)$ cannot be improved upon.(The bound is attained if Xi takes the values 0 and n(p+t) with respective probabilities $t/l(\mu+t)$ and $\mu/(\mu +t)$, and X2 = ... =Xn =0 with probability one.) Thus the assumption that the Xi are bounded on both sides is crucial to getting any improvement over Markov's bound."

If this is the case, I would like to better understand the implications of this. Does this mean that when I run the Empirical Bernstein bound to estimate the difference between 2 normally distributed variables, then an algorithm based on the Bernstein inequality would give the same result as one based on the Markov inequality?